# Does the CloudConfigurationManager GetSetting method cache?

Tags: .net, azure

Does anyone know if you take a performance hit calling CloudConfigurationManager GetSetting method?  Does it reparse the azure file for example or is it cached?  Not sure if I should add my own caching/static variable to improve perf for something called often like a connection string.

Thanks

Comment: Just take a peek at the GetSetting Method using Reflector and let us know :)

Comment: Ha.  I posted to avoid doing that.  It isn't a top priority for me, but I'll probably do that and post back if I don't hear anything from anyone.

Comment: I don't think it's caching the value.

Comment: Probably a more important question is whether the performance of `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting()` makes it worthy of caching setting values within our own applications. I'd be interested in anyone taking the time to measure it .. but not interested enough to do it myself ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/Common/Configuration/AzureApplicationSettings.cs) is available on github.

If you take a look at the source you can see that it isn't doing any caching, so if you are seeing performance issues you may want to implement your own caching.

The body of `GetSetting` shows a simple return:

```
value = GetValue("ServiceRuntime", name, GetServiceRuntimeSetting);

if (value == null)
{
    value = GetValue("ConfigurationManager", name, n => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[n]);
}

return value;
```

Comment: Your answer could possibly be improved by adding a relevant snip of code from the source.  In fact your link is no longer valid. :(

Comment: I updated the link, there's a fair bit of code you have to read to see that it's not caching probably too much to paste here.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like it caches, but it's not obvious from the code you posted whether that's the case. It passes the call through to `GetServiceRuntimeSetting` which might cache values for all I know.

Comment: But `ConfigurationManager` caches values, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer might not be correct.

It's true that `CloudConfigurationManager` itself does not cache, but that's because it internally delegates to `ConfigurationManager` or `WebConfigurationManager`, which **do cache values**.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx):

> For `<appSettings>` and `<connectionStrings>`, you use the AppSettings and
>   ConnectionStrings properties. These methods perform read-only
>   operations, use a single cached instance of the configuration, and are
>   multithread aware.

So that even if you access from `CloudConfigurationManager` directly, most probably, there would be no IO operation incurred.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not cached, as you suggested you would have to create you own caching for performance improvement.